# Exiting of an infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

I've written program to download images form soup.io.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request
import requests
import os.path

login = "test-site" #input('Enter soup login:')
website = "http://" + login + ".soup.io"
path = 'images'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

openWebsite = soup(urllib.request.urlopen(website), 'html.parser')
imageLink = openWebsite.find_all(name="div", attrs={'class': 'imagecontainer'})

i = 1
for src in imageLink:
    temp = src.find('img')['src']
    img_data = requests.get(temp).content
    if temp.find('.gif') != -1:
        filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.gif')
        with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
        i += 1
    elif temp.find('.jpeg') != -1:
        filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.jpeg')
        with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
        i += 1
    else:
        filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.png')
        with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
        i += 1

nextPage = openWebsite.find_all(name="a", attrs={'class': 'more keephash'})

while str(nextPage):
    for item in nextPage:
        nextPageLink = website+item['href']

        for j in nextPageLink:
            openWebsite = soup(urllib.request.urlopen(nextPageLink), "html.parser")
            imageLink = openWebsite.find_all(name="div", attrs={'class': 'imagecontainer'})
            nextPage = openWebsite.find_all(name="a", attrs={'class': 'more keephash'})

            for g in nextPage:
                nextPageLink = website + g['href']

            for src in imageLink:
                temp = src.find('img')['src']
                img_data = requests.get(temp).content
                if temp.find('.gif') != -1:
                    filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.gif')
                    with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
                        handler.write(img_data)
                    i += 1
                elif temp.find('.jpeg') != -1:
                    filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.jpeg')
                    with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
                        handler.write(img_data)
                    i += 1
                else:
                    filename = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.png')
                    with open(filename, 'wb') as handler:
                        handler.write(img_data)
                    i += 1
```

On every page there is displayed 20 images. At every page I'm scraping "More" link to older page (nextPageLink), and opening it after every image was saved in loop. My problem is that my program loops on the last page (Where is no "More" link) and downloads images over and over from there. I tried to assign nextPageLink to a new variable, called previousPage and then compare it using if statement - if the links are the same, I wanted to set nextPage = False, but it did not work - nextPageLink wasn't updated anymore, because there was no link on the site, so I couldn't compare it properly.

Comment: `if (scrape('more') == not found) { break }`, basically, in pseudo-code. if you fail to find a `more` link, then break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marc B suggested, my problem was that I haven't checked if nextPage is empty. So the solution was rather simple:

```
if openWebsite.find_all(name="a", attrs={'class': 'more keephash'}) == []:
   break
```